# getopt_long port to windows: __progname redefinition error

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-studio, getopt-long

I'm using a port of `getopt_long` for windows which has the following lines:

```
[...]
static char * __progname __P((char *));
int getopt_internal __P((int, char * const *, const char *));

static char * __progname(nargv0) char * nargv0;
{
    char * tmp;
    [...]
```

I'm not familiar with the synatx and works fine with a simple project but when I use it in a bigger project I get the following error while compiling:

```
..\getopt_long.c(52): error C2365: '__progname' : redefinition; previous definition was 'function'
      ..\getopt_long.c(49) : see declaration of '__progname'
```

I'm guessing there's a flag that tells `cl` not to expand `__progname(nargv0)`, do you know which one could it be? Is this information enough to spot the error? or might it be somewhere else?

Some of the flags:

```
 [...] /Zi /nologo /W1 /WX- /MP /O2 /Ob2 /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D _AMD64_ /D WITH_PNG /D WITH_OPENMP /D NDEBUG /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Release\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /MD /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /GR /openmp
```

and the working one:

```
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\CL.exe /c [...] /nologo /W1 /WX- /MP /O2 /Ob2 /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D WINDOWS /D NOMINMAX /D _AMD64_ /D NDEBUG /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Release\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /MD /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /GR /openmp [...] /Gd /TP /errorReport:queue ..\hello.cpp  /w
```

Comment: Does visual studio accept K&R style function definitions?  Can you show the preprocessed source?  Those macros are pretty confusing looking.

Comment: Does your "working" compilation work if you remove `/D WINDOWS` from it?

Comment: @CarlNorum What do you mean by preprocessed source, how do I get it? The full source can be found here: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Kerberos/Kerberos-47/KerberosFramework/Kerberos5/Sources/util/windows/getopt_long.c

Comment: Why do you say that's a port for windows?  Looks like Apple source to me.

Comment: @CarlNorum Well, OSX has POSIX, wouldn't it use unistd.h? Also, it's in a directory called `windows` and the syntax worked on MSVC straight away, so I just assumed they had ported getopt to windows, was I wrong?

Comment: @jxh Yes, it still builds removing WINDOWS and _WINDOWS flags.

Comment: The file you point to is the `getopt_long.c` source file, not `getopt_long.h`. I assumed the source fragment came from a header file that your `hello.cpp` program was also including. If you change the definition of the `__P(x)` macro from `x` to `()` instead, does it work?

Comment: @jxh Oops, yeah should be `getopt_long` without the `.h`, I was refering to the function. Thanks for spotting that out! fixed. The header is `getopt.h` http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Kerberos/Kerberos-47/KerberosFramework/Kerberos5/Sources/util/windows/getopt.h

Comment: @jxh I'll try what you suggest and let you know, but won't that change the behaviour?

Comment: @jxh I tried... with the same output. you've got any insight on what is actually happening? Are my suspects right?

Comment: @jxh Solved. THe error was elsewere, I was accidentally setting getopt_long.c source file properties to language CXX. thank you all for your time!